# Why is not the CSS applied with flex-mobile fields?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex-mobile

I am working with **flex-mobile**.

I created a CSS file within the same folder of my Views files :

```
/* CSS file */
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

s|Button {
    height: 25px;
    width: 120px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

Then I applied the CSS to my View :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Accueil" creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)" 
        >
    <fx:Style source="style.css" />
        ...
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Button id="go" label="Continuer" click="navigator.pushView(MyNewView)"/>
            <s:Button id="quit" label="Quitter" click="quitter(event)"/>
        </s:HGroup> ...
```

The problem is that at runtime the CSS is not applied ! So how to make the CSS be applied ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use HTML CSS Styles with a Flex Button.  They are two very different approaches to development and CSS Styles cannot be shared.

Look up the styles available on the Flex [Button](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html#styleSummary) as a reference and for more details.

But, briefly, height and width are properties, not styles.  They cannot be set with CSS.

text-shadow is not a valid style.  I'm not sure how you'd apply a shadow to the text.

border is not a valid style.  The proper way to change the border of a button would be to use a custom button skin.

border-radius, , -moz-border-radius, and -webkit-border-radius are not valid styles, but you may try [cornerRadius](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ButtonBase.html#style%3acornerRadius).

The color style should work, although color applies to the text in the button according to the docs; not the actual button.  I believe that you can use [chromeColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.html#style%3achromeColor) to change the button's color.

font-weight should be [fontWeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ButtonBase.html#style%3afontWeight).

It is my conclusions that your styles are being applied; however the Flex button does not recognize the styles you're trying to apply.

Comment: So how to apply CSS in flex-mobile ?

Comment: @pheromix Exactly the way you're doing it in your question.  You just have to use supported styles.  A list of Flex Button styles can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html#styleSummary